# Why is starring a post still allowed for read-only users in gallery mode chat rooms?

Tags: support, chat, abuse, chat-stars

The [recent mass star-trolling incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396154/what-is-stack-exchange-doing-to-fundamentally-fix-the-recent-and-ongoing-chat-di) made me realize that any registered user can star any message in read-only gallery chat rooms they don't have any write permission on.

This doesn't really seem to make sense since it allows a restricted user to interact with a room that they shouldn't be able to otherwise. I am therefore asking if this is something no one ever noticed, a bug or a deliberate choice based on some counterargument I am missing.

Comment: Already asked for here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239233/bringing-chat-moderation-to-a-stable-state

Comment: @RobertLongson not the dupe still, your is a request while mine is a question. If anything your linked post proves that this seems intentional since no one bothered to fix it in ***ten years***. Fell free to point that out in an answer if you want, I will upvote it.

Comment: Better change this into feature request clearly asking "Do not let read-only user star messages in chat" i.e. tie the star action to "post message" action, which makes some sense.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Nope, I am not requesting anything for now. First I want to see if there was a reason for this behavior that I can't see for some reason

Comment: I really don't think there's any reason, just overlook. Same as the fact that suspended users could not Bookmark questions, however they now [can Save posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383376/can-a-suspended-user-use-saves).

Comment: It seems worth noting that the [related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234520) is nearly 10 years old.

Comment: I don't see a good reason to prevent suspended users from using saves, since it accomplishes nothing they couldn't accomplish by private means (browser bookmarks).

Comment: Related: [Chat moderation tools are insufficient for combating star spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297793/chat-moderation-tools-are-insufficient-for-combating-star-spam). Per that post, even kick-muted users can star messages during their kick periods.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel technically ... saving posts affects related badges, so no, it does give suspended users an ability to affect the site in a way they can't using browser bookmarks.

Comment: If memory serves you can star things from the transcript without entering a room. That's a huge window for abuse in my opinion.