# What is Stack Exchange doing to fundamentally fix the recent and ongoing chat disruption through serial starring of messages?

Tags: support, chat, moderation, abuse, chat-stars

Many chatrooms right now have someone or something methodically starring every single recent message, disrupting the starboard messages and making stars effectively useless because they're on every single post. Some chatrooms have had this happen multiple times. It appears they can even bypass room protections like freezing and closing with this. I have personally seen this happen in Maid Café, The Bridge, This Is Fine, and I've heard reports from all over the network.

What is Stack Exchange going to do to make sure that it stops being an ongoing problem?

Comment: While it is annoying you can help out by either pinging an RO or moderator of the room you experience this to have stars cancelled.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Diamond moderators from around the network are working with staff to resolve the issue.

Publicly saying what steps are being taken to combat it would just make it easier to evade the restrictions, so don't expect to see many details released publicly at the moment. It's pretty standard for active troll situations to not publicly disclose what's being done.

Comment: Also, this very question fuels the troll(s) but guess it can't really be evaded.

Comment: I feel like "we're not going to tell what steps we'll take because it might help malicious actors to circumvent those steps" sounds a lot like security through obscurity. I might be mistaken about that though.

Comment: Social problems tend to be dealt with that way, because there tends not to be any other clear approach.

Comment: @Nzall My recollection of the idea of "security through obscurity" is not that one should never have a security scheme which employs obscuration, but that one should not *rely* on such a scheme.  Obscurity can (and often *should*) be part of a "swiss cheese" model of security.